# When integrating $\int \ln(\cos x)\,dx$, can I substitute $\cos x $ by $e^t$?

Tags: integration

$$\int \ln(\cos x)\,dx$$ In this integral can I substitute $\cos x$ by $e^t$? by proceeding this way i am using byparts but is looping back to the point from which i have started

Comment: You can try. Then differentiate the answer you come up with to see if it has the derivative you want.

Comment: i have integrated it but didn't differentiated that. can you give me insight about can i substitute any function with any other?

Comment: You could also use the complex definition of $\cos$ : $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})$$

Comment: If you [edit] the question to show us your work we may be able to help you find your error.

Comment: HINT: $ \cos x= \mathbb {R} (e^{ix})$

Comment: You can, but you have to change the differential accordingly, i.e. $$dx=-\dfrac{e^t}{\sqrt{1-e^{2t}}} dt$$ I don't think the correcponding integral will be much easier to solve

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives an answer involving the [polylogarithm function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html), which seems about right to me. This is not going to have an elementary form.

Comment: can you please give a introduction to what is polylogarithm function